# Send email results in "missing required authentication"

Tags: php, laravel, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-php-client

I'm new to this API and currently trying to send email by Gmail. I have Laravel installed and required by composer google/apiclient:"^2.7".

That's how I call create message and send functions

```
        $message = $this->googleApi->createMessage($user->name, $user->email, 'An email', $text);

        $client = new Google_Client();
        $service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
        $userId = 'my-google-id.apps.googleusercontent.com'

        $sendMessage = $this->googleApi->sendMessage($service, $userid, $message);
```

class to create message for API:

```
 public function createMessage($sender, $to, $subject, $messageText)
    {
        $message = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
        $subjectCharset = $charset = 'utf-8';


        $messageBody = 'Hello';
        $boundary = uniqid(rand(), true);
        $rawMessageString = "From: <{$sender}>\r\n";
        $rawMessageString .= "To: <{$to}>\r\n";
        $rawMessageString .= 'Subject: =?' . $subjectCharset . '?B?' . base64_encode($subject) . "?=\r\n";
        $rawMessageString .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $rawMessageString .= 'Content-type: Multipart/Mixed; boundary="' . $boundary . '"' . "\r\n";
        $rawMessageString .= "\r\n--{$boundary}\r\n";
        $rawMessageString .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=' . $charset . "\r\n";
        $rawMessageString .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . "\r\n\r\n";
        $rawMessageString .= str_replace("\n","",$messageBody)."\r\n";
        $rawMessageString .= "--{$boundary}\r\n";

        $rawMessage = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($rawMessageString), '+/', '-_'), '=');
        $message->setRaw($rawMessage);
        return $message;
    }
```

class to send email:

```
    public function sendMessage($service, $userId, $message)
    {
        try {
            $request = $service->users_messages->send($userId, $message);
            return $request;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

But for some reason when I trying to pull this out it responds with

```
{ "error": { "code": 401, "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.", "errors": [ { "message": "Login Required.", "domain": "global", "reason": "required", "location": "Authorization", "locationType": "header" } ], "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED" } }
```

I'm sorta stuck. Can you elaborate what it does want from me? ID of client was provided, though it says I'm not unauthenticated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to init the Google_client properly [PHP quick start](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php).  If its not popping up and requesting authorization then its not working right.

I recommend starting with the quick start first. Once you have that working you should be able to alter it to send mails rather than just list labels.

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Gmail API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_READONLY);
    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}


// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

// Print the labels in the user's account.
$user = 'me';
$results = $service->users_labels->listUsersLabels($user);

if (count($results->getLabels()) == 0) {
  print "No labels found.\n";
} else {
  print "Labels:\n";
  foreach ($results->getLabels() as $label) {
    printf("- %s\n", $label->getName());
  }
}
```

## verification

Note about gmail api and the send mail scope.  Verification for this scope is going to take time as it is done by a third party company.  I recommend you start early.

Comment: your going to have to change the path to the credential.json file, so that it can find it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you also take a look on my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65706273/send-email-by-google-api